# Extrair o conteúdo de uma pagina JSP para uma String em um servlet ou classe Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de verificar se alguém sabe como extrair o conteúdo de uma pagina JSP para uma String. Exemplo:

Tenho uma pagina JSP com conteúdo em HTML, quero passar este conteudo HTML para uma String na linguagem Java, para poder enviar este conteúdo HTML por e-mail através do HtmlEmail, agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: Poste aí o que vc já pesquisou, códigos que vc já tentou... aí fica mais fácil ver quais caminhos vc já tentou seguir e por conseqüência, mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Bom dia, ja pesquisei que vou ter que fazer o que eu quero provavelmente em um servlet, a minha maior dificuldade no momento é chamar um servlet dentro de uma classe java, pois minha aplicação é desktop, muito obrigado pelo retorno